# how to print the no. of ways a given integer can be represented in sum of different numbers?

Tags: c, algorithm

Suppose I have a number 5, Now the possible combinations of sum for representing 5 are :

4 + 1

3 + 2

3 + 1 + 1

2 + 2 + 1

2 + 1 + 1 + 1

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

How can we create a program for this in C?

Comment: Just a clue. Try dynamic programming.

Comment: This is the complete opposite of dynamic programming. They need downvotes for comments..

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi : How can you be sure that this is a homework assignment ? You are so sure that you even added the tag ...

Comment: The [usual way to solve this](http://www.programminglogic.com/integer-partition-algorithm/) involves dynamic programming.  Not sure why all the upvotes for @Blidy's comment.

Comment: The question title asks about the number of partitions, the answers present ways to generate all partitions. The question body suggests the latter, but is compatible with the title too. Can you clarify what you want? The answer is quite different for both tasks.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft My guess is they want downvotes for comments too.

Comment: How are 3+1+1 and 1+1+1+1 and 2+2+1 valid solutions -- you say you want sum of *different* numbers.  (Please also see @DanielFischer comment above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *LIST;   /* result work list */
int LEVEL=-1;/* partition level */

void print (void){
    int i;

    for(i=LEVEL;i>=0;--i){
        printf("%d",LIST[i]);
        if(i!=0)
            printf(" + ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void part(int n){
    int i, first; /* first is last-1  */

    if(n<1) return ;
    LIST[++LEVEL]=n; /* add list tail */
    print();

    first=(LEVEL==0) ? 1 : LIST[LEVEL-1];

    for(i=first;i<=n/2;i++){ /* candidate > first */
        LIST[LEVEL]=i; /* last element replace */
        part(n-i);
    }
    LEVEL--;
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int N;

    N=(argc>1)?atoi(argv[argc-1]):5;

    LIST=(int *)calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    if(LIST==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory\n");
        return -1;
    }

    part(N);
    free(LIST);

    return 0;
}
/* result
5
4 + 1
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
3 + 2
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me say that differently (to help with recursion):

All different combination that sum to 5 are composed of

- 4 + all combinations that sum to 1 beginning with at most 4
- 3 + all combinations that sum to 2 beginning with at most 3
- 2 + all combinations that sum to 3 beginning with at most 2
- 1 + all combinations that sum to 4 beginning with at most 1

Comment: This will count some combinations more than once

Comment: @BlueRaja: did you take into account the part that says "begining with at most #"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function that returns an array of sets:

Set[] SumComb(int n) {
  If n == 1 return { 1 };
  Set[] ResultN_1 = SumComb(n-1);
  Set[] ResultN;
  for each set S in ResultN_1 {
    Insert { S , 1 } to ResultN
    for each element E in S {
      Let TmpS = S
      Remove E from TmpS
      Increment E
      Add E to TmpS
      Sort TmpS
      Insert TmpS to ResultN if not already inserted
    } 
  }
}
```